# How can I know (from a web page) if there is any app registered with the browser to handle X schema? (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, browser

How can I know (from a web page) if there is any app registered with the browser to handle X schema? (Mac OS X)

For example, I have an App that then runs, it register that it can handle the schema my-app://. How can I write a web page (probably with js) to determine if I show the text "Download MyApp" or I just put the link to my-app://something been sure that it will be correctly open by my app?